# CSS not properly displaying with jQuery Post

Tags: jquery

I have 2 check boxes at the moment for a product filtering I'm working on. When you select a vehicle make the vehicle models automatically populated depending on the vehicle make. This issue I am having is that when the vehicle models populate my css does not work properly.

I have the check boxes within a certain height and scrollable but once my jquery script returns the vehicle model list its not longer scrollable and the models are just in a long list.

**checkboxes in php page**

```
<div class="showmake">
<!-- Make Side Filter START -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingfoure">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseMakes" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMakes">Refine By Make</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseMakes" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingfoure">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="cs-select-model">
                    <ul class="cs-checkbox-list mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark">
                    <?php
                        // connect to database
                        include 'config/config.php';
                        include 'config/opendb.php';

                        $chkbx = 0;
                        $sql="SELECT make, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM vehicles GROUP BY make ASC";                                                       
                        $rs=$conn->query($sql);

                        $rs->data_seek(0);
                        while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $chkbx++;
                            echo"<li>
                                     <div class='checkbox'>
                                         <input type='checkbox' name='makes[]' value='{$row['make']}' id='{$row['make']}' class='makes' />
                                         <label for='{$row['make']}'>{$row['make']}</label>
                                         <span>({$row['cnt']})</span>
                                     </div>
                                 </li>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Make Side Filter END -->
<!-- Model Side Filter START -->
<div class="showmodel">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingfoure">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseModels" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseModels">Refine By Model</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseModels" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingfoure">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="cs-select-model">
                    <ul class="cs-checkbox-list mCustomScrollbar models" data-mcs-theme="dark" name="models">
                     <?php
                         $chkbx = 0;
                         $sql="SELECT model, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM vehicles GROUP BY model ASC";
                         $rs=$conn->query($sql);
                         $rs->data_seek(0);

                         while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
                             $chkbx++;
                             echo"<li>
                                      <div class='checkbox'>
                                          <input type='checkbox' name='models[]' value='{$row['model']}' id='{$row['model']}' class='models' />
                                           <label for='{$row['model']}'>{$row['model']}</label>
                                           <span>({$row['cnt']})</span>
                                       </div>
                                   </li>";
                          }
                      ?>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Model Side Filter END -->
```

**jQuery Function**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showmodel").hide();
    $('.makes').on('change',function(){ //on checkboxes check

        //sending checkbox value into serialize form
        var hi=$('.makes:checked').serialize();
        var hi2=$('.models:checked').serialize();

        if(hi){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "vehiclefilter.php",
                data:{make:hi,
                    model:hi2},
                success: function(response){
                    document.getElementById('getdata').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML = response;
                    $('#result').hide();
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "vehiclemodels.php",
                data:{make:hi,
                    model:hi2},
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $(".models").html(html);
                }
           });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "vehiclefilter.php",
                data:{make:hi,
                    model:hi2,
                success: function(response){
                    document.getElementById('getdata').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML = response;
                    $('#result').hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**vehiclemodels.php**

```
<?php

// connect to database
include 'config/config.php';
include 'config/opendb.php';

if(!empty($_POST['make'])) {
    //unserialize to jquery serialize variable value
    $makeis=array();
    parse_str($_POST['make'],$makeis); //changing string into array

    //split 1st array elements
    foreach($makeis as $manufacturer){
        $manufacturer;
    }

    $manufacturers=implode("','",$manufacturer); //change into comma separated value to sub array
    $sql="SELECT model, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM vehicles WHERE make IN ('$manufacturers') GROUP BY model ASC";

    // query database
    $rs=$conn->query($sql);
    $rs->data_seek(0);

    while($rows = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="<?php echo"{$rows['model']}";?>" id="<?php echo"{$rows['model']}";?>" class="models" />
                <label for="<?php echo"{$rows['model']}";?>"><?php echo"{$rows['model']}";?></label>
                <span>(<?php echo"{$rows['cnt']}";?>)</span>
            </div>
        </li>
<?php

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Way to much code, please reduce it!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the change event works on page load, but when you run the ajax, and then repopulate the html, then your original change event method doesn't work anymore because its referencing old html. You can get around this by using delegation. you put your onchange event on a wrapper element, that doesn't get repopulated. like this:

```
$('#collapseModels').on( "change", ".makes", function() {

});
```

Mind you, that might not work as you may not be able to delegate a change event. The alternative is to create assign your change event to a re-usable function as follows, and then unbind your existing make method, before updating the html, then rebind it again like this:

```
 var fnChangeMethod = function(){

           /* 
               your change event method here ....

            */


            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
              /*
                replace your code with this
             */
                $('.makes').unbind('change', fnChangeMethod);
                $(".models").html(html);
                $('.makes').on('change', fnChangeMethod);
            }
           /* 

              the rest of the method etc....

           */
}

$('.makes').on('change', fnChangeMethod);
```

It's important to unbind the orginal change event, becuase otherwise your browser can have a memory leak and on every ajax request, all the events don't get properly reset, and slows down to a grinding halt.

Comment: Thank you for your time and response steve but I am new to Jquery and I'm not sure how to implement your suggestions to modify my code. To be honest I thought it would be a simpler fix.